# How to use protobuf in google endpoints

Tags: java, protobuf-net, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm writing Google Endpoints application and I want to return protobuf object in my `@Api` class.

All the time I'm getting this error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':ExploreBackend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
>   There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: Object type ? extends xxx.model.proto.MainProtos$PlaceOrBuilder not supported.

This is my code:

```
@Api( ... )
public class CityApi {

    public List<MainProto.City> getCities() {
        return new ArrayList<MainProto.City>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use protobuf in google endpoints

You can not